# Why does my phone receive only 2G data?

Tags: mobile-data, motorola

I am using a dual sim smartphone with sim cards on both the slots. Sim card inserted in slot 1 receives 3G data but, the other sim card inserted in slot 2 receives only 2G data, even though 3G internet pack is activated.

I swapped the sim cards between the slots, believing that there might be an issue with the mobile network, but the same problem exists.

- My smartphone: Moto E 2nd Generation 3G
- Android version: 5.0.2

I have even changed the preferred network type to 3G for the sim in slot 2 (Settings -> Data Usage -> Mobile network settings ->Preferred network type) but, no change.

What could be the issue ?

Comment: Have you tried only using 1 Sim card? Maybe its your software

Comment: Not every device supports 3G or above on both SIM slots. I never tried to know whether it's HW or SW limitation but I know that this is a hard fact. My Micromax A110Q supports 3G on both slots but my Micromax A310 supports only in first slot.

Comment: Are you in 3G area?

Answer (score 0):

Thats how dual SIM in this model works. One sim supports WCDMA (3g) bandwitch, while the other one is only EDGE (2g).

Comment: The may be true but how do we verify your claim? Can you support your claim using a source?

Comment: I had this phone for a while and was wondering about it myself. So no source, just my own experience :-D